# Randomly repeat rows of dataframe

Tags: r

I want to increase the number of rows in my dataframe by randomly repeating the existing rows (or the most meaningful rows, ie the rows that represent the dataset) so that the number of rows match that of another dataframe.

Lets say the other dataframe is `mrna.count`, which has 13441 rows.

```
> nrow(mrna.count)
[1] 13441
```

And the dataframe-of-interest, `prot`, only has 178 rows. I want to increase the `nrow(prot)` to 13441.

```
> dim(prot)
[1] 178 175
```

My attempt returns a list of dataframes but I want only one dataframe.

```
protein <- lapply(1:nrow(mrna.count), function(x) prot[sample(nrow(prot), size = x, replace = TRUE),])
```

Input:

```
> dput(prot[1:5,1:5])
structure(list(TCGA.2K.A9WE.01 = c(0.188926557, 0.32718108, -0.194691117, 
0.190334105, -0.4208597615), TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01 = c(0.12354026575, 
0.10028027475, -0.20595222225, -0.26450453025, -0.34263506075
), TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01 = c(-0.196046266, -0.00864849600000012, 0.481444919, 
0.048551157, 0.3332741995), TCGA.2Z.A9J6.01 = c(0.209220311, 
0.355386269, 0.188494459, -0.089151463, -0.3560846405), TCGA.2Z.A9J7.01 = c(-0.0607107314999999, 
-0.0887603205, -0.2174384005, 0.4300315565, 0.248662399)), row.names = c("14-3-3_beta", 
"14-3-3_epsilon", "14-3-3_zeta", "4E-BP1", "4E-BP1_pS65"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the rows that represent the dataset"?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
prot[sample(rownames(prot), nrow(mrna.count), replace=TRUE), ]
```